# NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Tags: java, compilation

I'm trying to compile some java code I've written, but I keep getting this error:

`Error occured during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object`

I've searched around loads and completed many fixes, the most common solution for other people running the JDK on a 64-bit Windows 7 was that rt.jar was not unpacked, but I've fixed that and I'm still getting the error!

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Try some of the less common solutions :-).  Seriously, it sounds like you either have a broken Java installation or a broken bootclasspath option on your `java` command line.  Without more clues from you as to how you might have gotten into that state, it is hard to see how we can do better than offer guesses.

Comment: A complete reinstall of Java should probably fix it.

Comment: Windows? Try rebooting

Comment: `common solution for other people running the JDK on a 64-bit Windows 7 was that rt.jar was not unpacked` - I wonder why you need to unpack rt.jar. I'm running both Java and Windows 7 in 64bit and never needed to unpack any jar. Please post your complete `javac` command that produces that exception.

Comment: @RomanVottner
set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin;
javac -Xlint:unchecked *.java
pause